# Martingale property of negative Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B_t$ be Brownian motion, with $B_0=0$. Next define $M_t=-B_t$.

Have I understood it correctly that $M_t$ is not a Martingale?

$E[M_t]=0$

$E[M_{t+1}|M_t]=-M_t$ and therefore not a Martingale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying by a constant doesn't change the Martingale property: for $t>s$,
$$
E[M_t|M_s]=E[-B_t|M_s]=E[-B_t|B_s]=-E[B_t|B_s]=-B_s=M_s.
$$

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you for the quick response.